# Javascript variable declaration : what is "var myVariable = {}"?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm pretty new to plain old JavaScript and to JavaScript frameworks (such as Backbone.js, RequireJS, ...). As I was reading and trying to understand some JavaScript files that I got from a project at work (based on JQuery, Backbone and Require), I've encountered some variable declarations such as:

```
var myVariable = {}, itemList;
```

Could someone explain to me what the "{}" is?

PS: might be a silly question but it's definitely not that easy Googling for "{}" as keyword...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/ is pretty good for searching for characters google ignores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an empty Javascript object literal (A shorthand way of creating an object)

```
var myVariable = {};
```

is similar to

```
var myVariable = new Object();
```

Both expressions will create an empty object.

Answer (score 4):

`{}` is just the javascript way of defining a collection or object.

In this example, it is filled with an object literal

```
var apple = {
    type: "macintosh",
    color: "red",
    getInfo: function () {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    }
}

var featurelessApple = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

`myVariable` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals), or generic `object`.

For future reference you can easily see this by [using the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) in your browser. In Chrome

```
var myVariable = {}
console.log(myVariable);
```

This will then print out the entire object. In this

```
Object {}
```

Comment: + 1 for adding that's an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

That's an empty [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_literals).

Object literals consist in zero or more key/value pairs enclosed in curly braces. In your example, there are zero key/value pairs, so the object does not define any property.